# C# RegEx Replacement

Tags: .net, regex, replace, substring

I'm adding a profanity filter and what I would like to do is replace the word (or partial word) that's replaced with a string of equal length.  The equal length part is where I'm having difficulty.

So if the word being replaced is 3 characters long than I want the text it's replaced with to be 3 characters long.  I'm not sure how I can substring my replacement string to match the length of the word being replaced.

Here's my test method:

```
public static string ProfanityFilter(this string text)
{
    string pattern = @"\bword\b|\bword2\b|\banother*";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    string replacement = "*%$@^!#@!@$^()!";
    return regex.Replace(text, replacement);
}
```

So, if the word "another" is replaced, it would be replaced with "*%$@^!#".

If "word" is replaced it would be replaced with "*%$@^"

If "wording" is replaced it would be replaced with "*%$@^ing"

Update:

I ended up finding the solution...

I created a new method:

```
 public static string Censored(Match match)
        {
            string replacement = "*%$@^!#@!@$^()!";
            return replacement.Substring(0, match.Captures[0].Length);
        }
```

Then changed

```
return regex.Replace(text, replacement);
```

to

```
return regex.Replace(text, Censored);
```

Comment: Be aware that your new method, using the `Substring`, will throw an exception if the capture length exceeds the replacement string's length. A safer way would be to build up the replacement string from a set of different characters if you really want it to consist of all those different characters. Otherwise you can specify one character and build it up with the `String` constructor as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: Interesting to see what happens to "assign".

Comment: I'm aware that it could exceed it and there wasn't a check in there :)  I wasn't finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
string input = "foo word bar word2 foobar another";
string pattern = @"\b(?:word|word2|another)\b";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => new String('*', m.Length));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The idea is to use the overloaded [`Regex.Replace` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) that accepts a [`MatchEvaluator` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx). I am providing the `MatchEvaluator` via a lambda expression and accessing the `Match.Length` property to determine the length of the matched profanity.

I redid your pattern to have exact matches by placing the `\b` metacharacter at the start and end of the alternative matches. However, based on your "wording"  = "*%$@^ing" example, it seems you want to support partial matches. In that case you should omit the usage of `\b`.

Comment: I'll give it a try.  I found a way as well and updated my question with the method I found.  I'll accept yours after I try it out.